# Update a tibble and a dropdown when a button is clicked; update the tibble when choices are made in the dropdown

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I've created the Shiny app below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

tbl1 <- tibble(obs = as_factor(letters[1:3]), val = -1:1)
tbl2 <- tibble(obs = as_factor(letters[1:3]), val = 0:2)

flag_outliers <- function(tbl) {
  tbl %>% mutate(is_outlier = near(val, min(val)) | near(val, max(val)))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(6,
    radioButtons("tbl", "Select tibble", choices = c("tbl1", "tbl2")),
    actionButton("flag_w_func", "Flag outliers with function"),
    pickerInput(
      "user_choices", "Flag outliers yourself",
      letters[1:3], multiple = TRUE, options = pickerOptions(actionsBox = TRUE)
    )
  ),
  column(6, tableOutput("tbl_w_flags"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  tbl <- reactive(switch(input$tbl, tbl1 = tbl1, tbl2 = tbl2))
  
  tbl_w_flags <- reactive(flag_outliers(tbl())) # Not sure what this should be
  
  output$tbl_w_flags <- renderTable(tbl_w_flags())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This defines two tibbles, `tbl1` and `tbl2`, and allows the user to choose one; their choice is stored in `tbl` in the server function. I want to create another tibble in the server function called `tbl_w_flags` that's `tbl` plus an `is_outlier` column.

If the user clicks on the "Flag outliers with function" button, the `is_outlier` column should be set using `flag_outliers()`. Also, the dropdown list `user_choices` should display check marks next to the observations that have been flagged by `flag_outliers()` and those observations only.

If the user checks or unchecks observations in the dropdown list, the `is_outlier` column should be updated appropriately - the appropriate values should be changed to `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Thus, `tbl_w_flags` needs to be modified if the button is clicked or choices are made in the dropdown list, and the dropdown list needs to be modified if the button is clicked.

I don't have much Shiny experience and am struggling to figure out how to do this. Is this possible? If so, how can it be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed `tbl_w_flags` and directly updated `tbl()`, two reactive are not necessary here. I also used `reactiveVal` for `reactive` and added an `updatePickerInput` to also update the picker if the button is clicked

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

tbl1 <- tibble(obs = as_factor(letters[1:3]), val = -1:1)
tbl2 <- tibble(obs = as_factor(letters[1:3]), val = 0:2)

flag_outliers <- function(tbl) {
  tbl %>% mutate(is_outlier = near(val, min(val)) | near(val, max(val)))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(6,
         radioButtons("tbl", "Select tibble", choices = c("tbl1", "tbl2")),
         actionButton("flag_w_func", "Flag outliers with function"),
         pickerInput(
           "user_choices", "Flag outliers yourself",
           letters[1:3], multiple = TRUE, options = pickerOptions(actionsBox = TRUE)
         )
  ),
  column(6, tableOutput("tbl_w_flags"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  tbl <- reactiveVal()
  observe(tbl(switch(input$tbl, tbl1 = tbl1, tbl2 = tbl2)))
  
  observe(input$user_choices)
  
  observeEvent(input$flag_w_func, {
    old_tbl <- tbl()
    new_tbl <- flag_outliers(old_tbl)
    # Update reactive tbl and user_choice pickerInput
    tbl(new_tbl)
    new_choices <- new_tbl %>% filter(is_outlier) %>% pull(obs)
    updatePickerInput(session, "user_choices", selected = new_choices)
  })

  observeEvent(input$user_choices, {
    old_tbl <- tbl()
    new_tbl <- old_tbl %>% mutate(is_outlier = c(obs %in% input$user_choices))
    # Update reactive tbl()
    tbl(new_tbl)
  })
  output$tbl_w_flags <- renderTable(tbl())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edit:**
If you like to reset the picker whenever the tibble is changed (using the radio buttons), change your first observer to

```r
observe({
  tbl(switch(input$tbl, tbl1 = tbl1, tbl2 = tbl2))
  updatePickerInput(session, "user_choices", selected = character(0))
})
```